# Reuse another ASP.NET session (set Session ID)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-session

My problem is that when I open web application from Outlook in a separate IE window, the ASP.NET session is lost. This is (as described in several places) because in-memory cookie is lost.

So it goes like this:

1. User works with ASP.NET web application in Outlook, and this stores some info in ASP.NET session
2. User clicks Print to open new IE window with print-ready data
3. The new window has different ASP.NET session ID and can't access old data.

I think, maybe, if I pass ASP.NET session ID to new IE window, I can somehow "attach" to that session? Tell ASP.NET that this is the one that I need to be current?

Answer (score 1):

[Cookieless Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx#cookieless_topic2) might work for you.  Using that technology, the session id is included in the URL in a format similiar to `http://yourserver/folder/(session ID here)/default.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just getting rid of the session data to begin with?

Comment: Yes, but in a legacy app this won't be soon.